# Why is my chat app sometimes not receiving messages?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, polling

I'm building a chat web application and using interval polling. However, sometimes the messages sent by client A **is not received** by client B. This happens like once in 20 messages sent or so. A page refresh on client B would of course, cause the message to be loaded.

This is how it works :

I'm using sessions to store the time client A last polled the server. When I do the next poll, the server checks the database for messages with time(precise up to microseconds) greater than the last Polled time. After doing stuffs with the latest messages, the server will save the current time in a session data to be used as last polled time on the next, coming poll.

I understand that sessions save data privately so other users can't access it. So two clients are always polling the same server at different time.

What went wrong? Should I use cache as an alternative so that both clients poll the same server at the same time? P.s., I'm using Apache server and MySQL database.

Here's the polling code in laravel :

```
   public function index(){

        $currentPoll = round(microtime(true) * 1000);//calculate the current time in microseconds

        //if the session variable doesn't exist, set the lastPoll variable to 0
        if(!($lastPoll = Session::get('lastPoll'))){
              $lastPoll = 0;
        }

        $selectedMsgExists = Input::get('selectedMsgExists');//check whether messages exist in currently opened conversation

        //check if conversation is opened or not
        if(Input::has('selectedID')){
            $selectedID = Input::get('selectedID');
        }
        else{
            $selectedID = false;
        }

        $loginuser = User::find(Auth::user()->id);//get the currently logged in user
        if($selectedMsgExists=='false'&&$selectedID){
        //if messages has not been loaded but conversation exists, we take the first ten messages of the opened conversation.

            $allMessages = $loginuser->messages()->select('users.name')->join('users',function($join){
                $join->on('users.id','=','messages.user_id');
            })->where('conv_id','LIKE',$selectedID)->orderBy('microseconds','desc')->take(10);

            Session::put('lastPoll',$currentPoll);//save the session
            return array(false,$allMessages->get()->reverse());//return the latest messages. False is to indicate that the data returned is NOT a conversation
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide code. We can't see what's happening right now.

Comment: @dwhite.me code provided

Comment: Are your sure the messages are being posted to the database?

Comment: @dwhite.me Absolutely. like I said, a page refresh on client B would cause the messages to be loaded.

Comment: Does this happen if you increase the refresh period? (i.e. from 10ms to 50ms)

Comment: @dwhite.me do you mean the interval period that I poll? Currently I'm polling the server every 2 seconds. I'll try to increase it to 3 seconds and see how it goes.

Comment: @dwhite.me nope, it doesn't but some messages are loaded more than once. I reduced it to 1 second and some messages go missing more.

Comment: Things like this are pretty difficult to debug without being able to execute the code. It sounds like for some reason the query you're running isn't returning the message. What I would try first is to log all the raw queries, then when you get a message that doesn't come through inspect and run the query in question and you can see if that's the problem - if not you'll have to step through the rest of the code and find out where it's getting lost.

Comment: Another thing to consider... I would be most suspicious of querying by a time stamp here. If for some reason there's even as much as a 1 microsecond overlap you could miss a message. Perhaps instead of logging the time you could log the last retrieved ID (assuming you have incrementing ids on the messages) and then poll for messages with ID greater than that

Comment: @judereid You have a very good point. If you added that as an answer I might just accept it. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use ID, not time!**

I'll give credit to [judereid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732973/judereid) in his comments above.

```
Another thing to consider... I would be most suspicious of querying by a timestamp 
here. If for some reason there's even as much as a 1 microsecond overlap you could 
miss a message. Perhaps instead of logging the time you could log the last 
retrieved ID (assuming you have incrementing ids on the messages) and then poll 
for messages with ID greater than that –  judereid
```

After some adjustments, there don't seem to be any messages amiss. I guess the problem was really with using time to obtain the latest messages.